# Google analytics - get visits for subdomain without creating profiles?

Tags: google-analytics

http://www.bigdaylight.com/analytics/filtering-subdomains-in-google-analytics/

I wonder if there's a way to fetch stats for subdomain eg.

sub.mypage.com/examplepage - i can search by "examplepage" in GA panel and view this data and fetch this via Core Reporting API

sub.mypage.com/ - those visits are available under '/' in GA panel

Is there any way to fetch stats for second page without creating profiles? The issue is that i  am maintaing site, where we have 15 subdomains and creating and maintaing profile for each would rather painful.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to problem are roll up reports.

http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/09/advanced-structure-your-account-with.html